# How to unlock a bookmarked WF?

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-activity

I'm debugging my workflow and in doing so it did not currectly Unload the WF. Now when I try to resume the workflow I get a InstanceLockedException. How do I clear the lock? So I can try to resume the WF.

> The execution of an InstancePersistenceCommand was interrupted because the instance '3c960800-370b-4130-81f2-b067e5bc41b6' is locked by a different instance owner. This error usually occurs because a different host has the instance loaded. The instance owner ID of the owner or host with a lock on the instance is '51ac360e-11e3-41c2-a1c9-ca7c0784772d'.

Answer (score 0):

Try to abort the instance. Abort simply clears the in-memory workflow instance and can be restarted from the last persistence point.(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.workflow.runtime.workflowinstance.abort.aspx)